# FetchError: request to http://localhost:4006/graphql failed, reason: socket hang up

Tags: javascript, node.js

Getting socket hung up error. Following is the stacktrace

`

```
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/u01/apollo-ms/packages/api/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1455:11)"
2: "    at ClientRequest.elasticAPMCallbackWrapper (/u01/apollo-ms//packages/api/node_modules/elastic-apm-node/lib/instrumentation/index.js:358:27)"
3: "    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:209:13)"
4: "    at ClientRequest.req.emit (/u01/apollo-ms/packages/api/node_modules/elastic-apm-node/lib/instrumentation/http-shared.js:189:21)"
5: "    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:440:9)"
6: "    at Socket.emit (events.js:214:15)"
7: "    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1178:12)"
8: "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

`
Please help. Using to make the api call.

Comment: Could you show us your code? More specifically where you are making the request